# Making my website interactive with the size of the screen/browser

Tags: html, css, size, chart.js, interactive

I'm currently working on a small high school project where I need to make an interactive website using HTML and CSS. I have pretty much finished the website but am now wondering if there are any easy ways to make your website interactive with the size of your screen. Are there any plugins that can help me out or will I just have to do this with code such as this -

```
@media screen and (max-width:1310px) .container1{width 50%}
.main{width: 50%}
```

[image: My project]

[image: Project on different sized screen]

I'm pretty new to HTML so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap. It is a css framework for writing responsive website. It provides classes for different screen size.